# How do I proportionally edit all shape keys except for one?

Tags: shape-keys

I have an object with multiple shape keys. I want to edit the base shape whilst relative mode is enabled so that the edits proportionally affect all the rest of the shape keys except for one, which I would like to keep the same. I can't just edit the base shape and propagate the vertices to the desired shapes because the verts in question are not in the same position as the base in the other shape keys.

Is there a way to 'lock' this specific shape key so that it isn't affected by edits to the base mesh in relative mode?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure about how to edit all shapekeys.  I would have to do some playing to figure out how (if) I could do that.  But it sounds like you've got that part figured out already, with the exception that you need to *not* affect one shapekey.  And I can tell you how to do that part off the top of my head.

Before you edit all other shapekeys, simply duplicate your object.  Pin the "locked" shapekey on your duplicate (or set it to 1.0 and all other shapekeys to 0.)  Go ahead and edit your original however you'd like.  When you're done, select (in 3D viewport) your duplicate, then shift select your edited original.  In properties/object data/shapekeys, from the shapekey specials downward-pointing caret dropdown to the right of the list of shapekeys, select "join as shapes".  The shape of your pinned duplicate will be added as a new shapekey; you can delete the original version of this shapekey and rename your new one (if you'd like.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nathan, this workaround does work for what I need it to, even if it isn't the most ideal.